# Why web3 and not just call JSON RPC API

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, quorum

This might be a silly question. if one is able to call JSON RPC API methods such as eth_sendTransaction directly using Postman or any web client, albeit a little troublesome, why use web3?

I have been using web3 js in my DApp. Asking this for understanding.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Comment: The same reasons you would use any other library. I guess the main benefit is that it saves you from having to write and test the code yourself.

Comment: there might be cases where direct call to JSON RPC API is better as I am trying to integrate quorum with some existing systems which might support Ethereum JSON RPC API calls. If web3 is needed, I need to build a DApp and expose these methods as an endpoint thereby creating another middle tier. What do you think? I really wish to understand if there is a better way to put things together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you *can* do everything without web3. Most users just don't find it easy to do most of the things web3 does for you.

So web3 is just a wrapper library which provides easy-to-use access to various functionalities. It makes development a lot easier for those who are not hardcore blockchain enthusiasts (who don't want to write RPC calls). In doing that, it lowers the entry barrier into Ethereum world.

I *could* also write this answer with on-screen keyboard but it's just a lot easier to write with a real keyboard.

Comment: there might be cases where direct call to JSON RPC API is better as I am trying to integrate quorum with some existing systems which might support Ethereum JSON RPC API calls. If web3 is needed, I need to build a DApp and expose these methods as an endpoint thereby creating another middle tier. What do you think? I really wish to understand if there is a better way to put things together.

Comment: Nobody forces you to create a dapp or anything public. You can just use web3 with any environment which can run javascript - such as node. Check for example: https://medium.com/@codetractio/try-out-ethereum-using-only-nodejs-and-npm-eabaaaf97c80

Answer (score 1):

Like any other library, Web3.js is just trying to make things simple for you, the app developer.

You do not need to use it. In fact, you could literally rewrite all the work it does in your own code, but that would be an incredible waste of time.

Instead, Web3.js enables app developers to build things quickly and simply.

For example, get the [balance of an Ethereum Address](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/ETH-Balance) in 40 lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
                window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            } else {
                console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
                window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/<APIKEY>"));
            }
        })
        function getBalance() {
            var address, wei, balance
            address = document.getElementById("address").value
            try {
                web3.eth.getBalance(address, function (error, wei) {
                    if (!error) {
                        var balance = web3.fromWei(wei, 'ether');
                        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = balance + " ETH";
                    }
                });
            } catch (err) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = err;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ETH Balance Fetcher</h1>
    <p>Enter your Ethereum Address:</p>
    <input type="text" size="50" id="address" />
    <button type="button" onClick="getBalance();">Get Balance</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Imagine having to implement:

- Connecting to a Web3 provider
- Integrating the `getBalance` function
- Converting from Wei to Ether
- etc...

Comment: there might be cases where direct call to JSON RPC API is better as I am trying to integrate quorum with some existing systems which might support Ethereum JSON RPC API calls. If web3 is needed, I need to build a DApp and expose these methods as an endpoint thereby creating another middle tier. What do you think? I really wish to understand if there is a better way to put things together.

Answer (score 0):

Web3 is just a javascript wrapper for the JSON RPC API which can be used to interact with your ethereum node without writing raw JSON RPC calls.

This doesn't mean that web3 is required, you can use other library (ethers.js - still javascript) or do raw call in case the language your using to develop your DApp doesn't have any JSON RPC client for Ethereum.

So in case you're doing something standard just use the libraries already created by the community, if not you can create your own in case there's nothing or you're doing something custom (eg. your private blockchain with custom RPC API in a controlled environment)

Answer (score -1):

Wow, I feel much smarter and way dumber after reading the content and then scrolling back up to the time stamp. Looks like Im about 4 years late to the game but all good! Ya'll take care, be well and thx very much for the assist!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/89242)